# Transform complex data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame whose 1st column (`weights`) contains a list (of data frames?):

```
> head(data$weights)

> data <- structure(list(A373R11 = structure(list(Signature.1A = 0, Signature.1B = 0, 
    Signature.2 = 0, Signature.3 = 0.151631702143023, Signature.4 = 0.149799882118262, 
    Signature.5 = 0, Signature.6 = 0, Signature.7 = 0.0634912587993959, 
    Signature.8 = 0, Signature.9 = 0.173189155080817, Signature.10 = 0, 
    Signature.11 = 0, Signature.12 = 0, Signature.13 = 0, Signature.14 = 0, 
    Signature.15 = 0, Signature.16 = 0, Signature.17 = 0, Signature.18 = 0, 
    Signature.19 = 0, Signature.20 = 0, Signature.21 = 0.0905517653558877, 
    Signature.R1 = 0, Signature.R2 = 0, Signature.R3 = 0, Signature.U1 = 0.155590748898003, 
    Signature.U2 = 0.145955461287919), .Names = c("Signature.1A", 
"Signature.1B", "Signature.2", "Signature.3", "Signature.4", 
"Signature.5", "Signature.6", "Signature.7", "Signature.8", "Signature.9", 
"Signature.10", "Signature.11", "Signature.12", "Signature.13", 
"Signature.14", "Signature.15", "Signature.16", "Signature.17", 
"Signature.18", "Signature.19", "Signature.20", "Signature.21", 
"Signature.R1", "Signature.R2", "Signature.R3", "Signature.U1", 
"Signature.U2"), row.names = "A373R11", class = "data.frame"), 
    A373R13 = structure(list(Signature.1A = 0, Signature.1B = 0, 
        Signature.2 = 0, Signature.3 = 0.221014874027829, Signature.4 = 0, 
        Signature.5 = 0, Signature.6 = 0, Signature.7 = 0, Signature.8 = 0.279252211893692, 
        Signature.9 = 0, Signature.10 = 0, Signature.11 = 0, 
        Signature.12 = 0, Signature.13 = 0, Signature.14 = 0, 
        Signature.15 = 0, Signature.16 = 0, Signature.17 = 0, 
        Signature.18 = 0, Signature.19 = 0.115216422668955, Signature.20 = 0, 
        Signature.21 = 0, Signature.R1 = 0, Signature.R2 = 0, 
        Signature.R3 = 0.0636987713225648, Signature.U1 = 0.108875099907467, 
        Signature.U2 = 0), .Names = c("Signature.1A", "Signature.1B", 
    "Signature.2", "Signature.3", "Signature.4", "Signature.5", 
    "Signature.6", "Signature.7", "Signature.8", "Signature.9", 
    "Signature.10", "Signature.11", "Signature.12", "Signature.13", 
    "Signature.14", "Signature.15", "Signature.16", "Signature.17", 
    "Signature.18", "Signature.19", "Signature.20", "Signature.21", 
    "Signature.R1", "Signature.R2", "Signature.R3", "Signature.U1", 
    "Signature.U2"), row.names = "A373R13", class = "data.frame"), 
    A373R3 = structure(list(Signature.1A = 0, Signature.1B = 0, 
        Signature.2 = 0, Signature.3 = 0.0795605471131758, Signature.4 = 0.0973130562439999, 
        Signature.5 = 0, Signature.6 = 0, Signature.7 = 0, Signature.8 = 0.249674548796242, 
        Signature.9 = 0.0725013504411567, Signature.10 = 0, Signature.11 = 0.064665155855146, 
        Signature.12 = 0, Signature.13 = 0, Signature.14 = 0, 
        Signature.15 = 0, Signature.16 = 0, Signature.17 = 0, 
        Signature.18 = 0, Signature.19 = 0, Signature.20 = 0, 
        Signature.21 = 0, Signature.R1 = 0, Signature.R2 = 0, 
        Signature.R3 = 0.0703546703126821, Signature.U1 = 0.21753544296676, 
        Signature.U2 = 0.0739201832004727), .Names = c("Signature.1A", 
    "Signature.1B", "Signature.2", "Signature.3", "Signature.4", 
    "Signature.5", "Signature.6", "Signature.7", "Signature.8", 
    "Signature.9", "Signature.10", "Signature.11", "Signature.12", 
    "Signature.13", "Signature.14", "Signature.15", "Signature.16", 
    "Signature.17", "Signature.18", "Signature.19", "Signature.20", 
    "Signature.21", "Signature.R1", "Signature.R2", "Signature.R3", 
    "Signature.U1", "Signature.U2"), row.names = "A373R3", class = "data.frame"), 
    A373R5 = structure(list(Signature.1A = 0, Signature.1B = 0, 
        Signature.2 = 0, Signature.3 = 0.113996509522102, Signature.4 = 0.114874220936966, 
        Signature.5 = 0.142056872670519, Signature.6 = 0, Signature.7 = 0, 
        Signature.8 = 0.208376707959741, Signature.9 = 0.0744527503782136, 
        Signature.10 = 0, Signature.11 = 0, Signature.12 = 0, 
        Signature.13 = 0, Signature.14 = 0, Signature.15 = 0.0771902641012979, 
        Signature.16 = 0, Signature.17 = 0, Signature.18 = 0, 
        Signature.19 = 0, Signature.20 = 0, Signature.21 = 0, 
        Signature.R1 = 0, Signature.R2 = 0, Signature.R3 = 0, 
        Signature.U1 = 0.0673567355607731, Signature.U2 = 0), .Names = c("Signature.1A", 
    "Signature.1B", "Signature.2", "Signature.3", "Signature.4", 
    "Signature.5", "Signature.6", "Signature.7", "Signature.8", 
    "Signature.9", "Signature.10", "Signature.11", "Signature.12", 
    "Signature.13", "Signature.14", "Signature.15", "Signature.16", 
    "Signature.17", "Signature.18", "Signature.19", "Signature.20", 
    "Signature.21", "Signature.R1", "Signature.R2", "Signature.R3", 
    "Signature.U1", "Signature.U2"), row.names = "A373R5", class = "data.frame"), 
    A373R9 = structure(list(Signature.1A = 0, Signature.1B = 0, 
        Signature.2 = 0, Signature.3 = 0.116847300193985, Signature.4 = 0, 
        Signature.5 = 0.21624751052703, Signature.6 = 0, Signature.7 = 0, 
        Signature.8 = 0.252498230882402, Signature.9 = 0, Signature.10 = 0, 
        Signature.11 = 0.119495912880994, Signature.12 = 0, Signature.13 = 0, 
        Signature.14 = 0, Signature.15 = 0, Signature.16 = 0, 
        Signature.17 = 0, Signature.18 = 0, Signature.19 = 0, 
        Signature.20 = 0, Signature.21 = 0, Signature.R1 = 0, 
        Signature.R2 = 0, Signature.R3 = 0.0725549911220892, 
        Signature.U1 = 0, Signature.U2 = 0), .Names = c("Signature.1A", 
    "Signature.1B", "Signature.2", "Signature.3", "Signature.4", 
    "Signature.5", "Signature.6", "Signature.7", "Signature.8", 
    "Signature.9", "Signature.10", "Signature.11", "Signature.12", 
    "Signature.13", "Signature.14", "Signature.15", "Signature.16", 
    "Signature.17", "Signature.18", "Signature.19", "Signature.20", 
    "Signature.21", "Signature.R1", "Signature.R2", "Signature.R3", 
    "Signature.U1", "Signature.U2"), row.names = "A373R9", class = "data.frame"), 
    A512R19 = structure(list(Signature.1A = 0.109490572493859, 
        Signature.1B = 0, Signature.2 = 0, Signature.3 = 0, Signature.4 = 0.22010156823306, 
        Signature.5 = 0, Signature.6 = 0, Signature.7 = 0, Signature.8 = 0, 
        Signature.9 = 0, Signature.10 = 0, Signature.11 = 0, 
        Signature.12 = 0, Signature.13 = 0, Signature.14 = 0, 
        Signature.15 = 0, Signature.16 = 0, Signature.17 = 0, 
        Signature.18 = 0, Signature.19 = 0, Signature.20 = 0, 
        Signature.21 = 0, Signature.R1 = 0, Signature.R2 = 0, 
        Signature.R3 = 0.150943894106973, Signature.U1 = 0.248556502648564, 
        Signature.U2 = 0.119306892617062), .Names = c("Signature.1A", 
    "Signature.1B", "Signature.2", "Signature.3", "Signature.4", 
    "Signature.5", "Signature.6", "Signature.7", "Signature.8", 
    "Signature.9", "Signature.10", "Signature.11", "Signature.12", 
    "Signature.13", "Signature.14", "Signature.15", "Signature.16", 
    "Signature.17", "Signature.18", "Signature.19", "Signature.20", 
    "Signature.21", "Signature.R1", "Signature.R2", "Signature.R3", 
    "Signature.U1", "Signature.U2"), row.names = "A512R19", class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("A373R11", 
"A373R13", "A373R3", "A373R5", "A373R9", "A512R19"))
```

Here, each row contains a sample, and each column contains a score for a particular signature:

```
> data[1]

$A373R11
        Signature.1A Signature.1B Signature.2 Signature.3 Signature.4 Signature.5 Signature.6 Signature.7 Signature.8 Signature.9 Signature.10 Signature.11
A373R11            0            0           0   0.1516317   0.1497999           0           0  0.06349126           0   0.1731892            0            0
        Signature.12 Signature.13 Signature.14 Signature.15 Signature.16 Signature.17 Signature.18 Signature.19 Signature.20 Signature.21 Signature.R1 Signature.R2
A373R11            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0   0.09055177            0            0
        Signature.R3 Signature.U1 Signature.U2
A373R11            0    0.1555907    0.1459555
```

I would like to transfer this into a dataframe with the following structure:

```
sample  signature  score
A373R11  Signature.1A  0
A373R11  Signature.1B  0
[...]
A373R13  Signature.1A  0
A373R13  Signature.1B  0
[...]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Given example `data` doesn't contain `weights`

Comment: @PoGibas - thanks - have updated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two approaches:

**1) with the data.table-package**

Using:

```
library(data.table)
melt(rbindlist(data, idcol = 'sample'),
     id = 'sample', variable.name = 'signature', value.name = 'score')
```

gives:

> ```
>       sample    signature      score
>   1: A373R11 Signature.1A 0.00000000
>   2: A373R13 Signature.1A 0.00000000
>   3:  A373R3 Signature.1A 0.00000000
>   4:  A373R5 Signature.1A 0.00000000
>   5:  A373R9 Signature.1A 0.00000000
>  ---                                
> 158: A373R13 Signature.U2 0.00000000
> 159:  A373R3 Signature.U2 0.07392018
> 160:  A373R5 Signature.U2 0.00000000
> 161:  A373R9 Signature.U2 0.00000000
> 162: A512R19 Signature.U2 0.11930689
> ```

**2) with base R**

Using:

```
dat2 <- do.call(rbind, dat)
reshape(dat2, idvar = 'sample', ids = row.names(dat2),
        varying = list(1:ncol(dat2)), times = colnames(dat2),
        timevar = 'signature', v.names = 'score',
        new.row.names = NULL, direction = 'long')
```

gives:

> ```
>                         signature      score  sample
> A373R11.Signature.1A Signature.1A 0.00000000 A373R11
> A373R13.Signature.1A Signature.1A 0.00000000 A373R13
> A373R3.Signature.1A  Signature.1A 0.00000000  A373R3
> A373R5.Signature.1A  Signature.1A 0.00000000  A373R5
> A373R9.Signature.1A  Signature.1A 0.00000000  A373R9
>
> .....
>
> A373R13.Signature.U2 Signature.U2 0.00000000 A373R13
> A373R3.Signature.U2  Signature.U2 0.07392018  A373R3
> A373R5.Signature.U2  Signature.U2 0.00000000  A373R5
> A373R9.Signature.U2  Signature.U2 0.00000000  A373R9
> A512R19.Signature.U2 Signature.U2 0.11930689 A512R19
> ```

---

NOTE:

It is better not to give your data the same name as a function. See `?data`.

Answer (score 7):

A `tidyverse` solution, where we first join all the data.frames together, then use `gather` to reshape them as desired:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  bind_rows(.id = 'sample') %>%
  gather(signature, score, -sample)
```

Gives:

> ```
>      sample    signature      score
> 1   A373R11 Signature.1A 0.00000000
> 2   A373R13 Signature.1A 0.00000000
> 3    A373R3 Signature.1A 0.00000000
> 4    A373R5 Signature.1A 0.00000000
> 5    A373R9 Signature.1A 0.00000000
> 6   A512R19 Signature.1A 0.10949057
> 7   A373R11 Signature.1B 0.00000000
> 8   A373R13 Signature.1B 0.00000000
> 9    A373R3 Signature.1B 0.00000000
> 10   A373R5 Signature.1B 0.00000000
> ....
> ```

Can be written as a one-liner without pipes as:

```
gather(bind_rows(data, .id = 'sample'), signature, score, -sample)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a base R alternative with `rapply`. Note that I've renamed your data.frame dat.

```
# pull out the values and their attached names with rapply
myVec <- rapply(unname(dat), identity)
# even better:
# myVec <- unlist(unname(dat))

# construct the data.frame
mydf <- data.frame(sample=rep(names(dat), lengths(dat)),
                   signature=names(myVec),
                   score=myVec,
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE, row.names = seq_along(myVec))
```

This returns

```
 head(mydf)
   sample    signature     score
1 A373R11 Signature.1A 0.0000000
2 A373R11 Signature.1B 0.0000000
3 A373R11  Signature.2 0.0000000
4 A373R11  Signature.3 0.1516317
5 A373R11  Signature.4 0.1497999
6 A373R11  Signature.5 0.0000000
```

By default, `rapply` performs a function on the final elements of each list an returns a vector. I use `identity` to return these elements unaltered. Since each element has a name associated with it, `rapply` returns a named vector.

I use `unname` to strip off the names of each outer list items. This makes the data construction in the next step a little easier. Otherwise, the named vector would have names like "A373R11.Signature.5" which would require more work to return the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

First you combine data.frames (`rbind`), then you turn them into matrix to keep rownames and melt that.

```
library(data.table)    
res <- melt(as.matrix(do.call(rbind, data)))
colnames(res) <- c("sample", "signature", "score")
```

Cleaner solution with pipes

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

res <- data %>%
    do.call(rbind, .) %>%
    as.matrix() %>%
    melt() %>%
    setDT() %>%
    setnames(c("sample", "signature", "score"))
```